# Tor Browser-how to verify signature?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, verification

Downloaded the file for Win7, also Gpg4Win. Mentioned .asc file did not accompany Tor, in spite of the description on the Torsite. Other ways of verification I could not find. 
Nevertheless I followed the description involving Gpg4Win under "How to verify signatures for packages" via cmd.exe, it did not work.

How can I verify Tor Browser?

PS:Gpg seems not to be in English available?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the .asc file yourself. Click the "(sig)" part under the purple download button, left of the language selector:
https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en

EDIT: I had problems with using the full path to GnuPG as well, go to the folder first:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnu\GnuPg
```

(This is for 64 bit windows, for 32 bit windows; remove the (x86)
After that you just type gpg.exe with the commands you want to use, e.g.:

```
gpg.exe --keyserver x-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x416F061063FEE659
```

Comment: Please look above-that is the problem!

Comment: @user63888 My mistake, edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Tor Browser Bundle download [page.](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) Select the correct download, and download! Below the nice, purple button should be a link that says sig. Don't left click but instead right click it. Then select Save Link As in the context menu. (In Firefox, I don't know in the rest, sorry. In Safari I believe you Alt click the link.)

Once downloaded verify as normal. From [Tor Project Docs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) (It contains instructions for Mac and Linux as well.)

> You need to have GnuPG installed before you can verify signatures.
>   Download it from http://gpg4win.org/download.html.
>
> Once it's installed, use GnuPG to import the key that signed your
>   package. Since GnuPG for Windows is a command-line tool, you will need
>   to use cmd.exe. Unless you edit your PATH environment variable, you
>   will need to tell Windows the full path to the GnuPG program. If you
>   installed GnuPG with the default values, the path should be something
>   like this: C:\Program Files\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe.
>
> Erinn Clark signs the Tor Browser Bundles. Import her key
>   (0x416F061063FEE659) by starting cmd.exe and typing:
>
> "C:\Program Files\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe" --keyserver
>   x-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x416F061063FEE659
>
> After importing the key, you can verify that the fingerprint is
>   correct:
>
> "C:\Program Files\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe" --fingerprint 0x416F061063FEE659
>
> You should see:
>
> ```
> pub   2048R/63FEE659 2003-10-16
>       Key fingerprint = 8738 A680 B84B 3031 A630  F2DB 416F 0610 63FE E659
> uid                  Erinn Clark <erinn@torproject.org>
> uid                  Erinn Clark <erinn@debian.org>
> uid                  Erinn Clark <erinn@double-helix.org>
> sub   2048R/EB399FD7 2003-10-16
> ```
>
> To verify the signature of the package you downloaded, you will need
>   to download the ".asc" file as well. Assuming you downloaded the
>   package and its signature to your Desktop, run:
>
> "C:\Program Files\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe" --verify
>   C:\Users\Alice\Desktop\tor-browser-2.3.25-13_en-US.exe.asc
>   C:\Users\Alice\Desktop\tor-browser-2.3.25-13_en-US.exe
>
> The output should say "Good signature":
>
> ```
> gpg: Signature made Wed 31 Aug 2011 06:37:01 PM EDT using RSA key ID 63FEE659
> gpg: Good signature from "Erinn Clark <erinn@torproject.org>"
> gpg:                 aka "Erinn Clark <erinn@debian.org>"
> gpg:                 aka "Erinn Clark <erinn@double-helix.org>"
> gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
> gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
> Primary key fingerprint: 8738 A680 B84B 3031 A630  F2DB 416F 0610 63FE E659
> ```
>
> Notice that there is a warning because you haven't assigned a trust
>   index to this person. This means that GnuPG verified that the key made
>   that signature, but it's up to you to decide if that key really
>   belongs to the developer. The best method is to meet the developer in
>   person and exchange key fingerprints.

Then install as normal by running the `.exe`, should be `torbrowser-install-X.Y.Z_LANGUAGE.exe` in my case `torbrowser-install-3.6.2_en-US.exe`. Tor Project has instructions in greater detail for [Windows,](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#windows) [Linux,](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux) and [Mac.](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#macosx)

Comment: Your post seems to be the copy from the Torsite. "Cannot find the path" said the terminal, I checked the location of the file, it is exactly what was written in the terminal, how can I fix this?  That was the reason of my post, after following the Tor-instructions.  Gpg4Win is installed! I find Gnu at 2 locations in C:, ProgramData and Programs(x86), I selected the latter as path.

Comment: @user63888 Yes, it is from the Tor site. (TorProject.org) What command did you enter into the command line?

Comment: I copied in the terminal:"C:\Program Files\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe" --keyserver x-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x416F061063FEE659

Comment: @user63888 How did you install GnuPG

Comment: I do not remember the installation process. It is listed, at least.

Comment: Can you please enter these into the command prompt and reply with the output `cd C:\Program Files\Gnu\GnuPg` then `dir`. (sorry for the prolonged response.)

Comment: Done as you described. After entering "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnu\GnuPg". Output: " C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnu\GnuPg". Appended "gpg.exe --keyserver x-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 0x416F061063FEE659" at mentioned output.

Comment: Entered that, tried to copy the output , but I do not know how-perhaps impossible? How should the output look like? Then: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Gnu\GnuPg>gpg.exe" --fingerprint 0x416F061063FEE659" That> character I do not know, it was there and could not be removed. After >I appended the "gpg.exe --fingerprint....enter. Terminal blamed "could not find "gpg.exe" --fingerprint 0x416F061063FEE659" or wrong written". What might be the mistake?