# Please Provide a Step by Step Guide to Upgrade Tor Browser Bundle on Ubuntu

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ubuntu

I'm a noob user of Ubuntu and Tor Browser Bundle. I have a flashing warning sign on the Tor button that I understand means I need to upgrade. I'd like a very simple step-by-step how-to if one exists - one for a terminal novice.

Comment: I believe that my answer to this question includes useful information not found in any of the answers to the older question. Is it OK to add my answer to the old question? Or would it be better to edit one of the answers for it?

Answer (score 1):

Download Tor Browser Bundle from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en). **VERIFY your download. Look at [this answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/tor-browser-how-to-verify-signature/3301#3301) or at the [docs.](https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en)** Tor Project recommends that you extract on top instead of replacing. To do so, extract in a folder then drag to containing folder of the original install. Click merge or replace if it asks. (Taken from my comment on mirimir's post.)

It is worth noting that Tor Project said that for heavily different updates this can break your install, in which case you have to backup and such. Mirimir's answer provides suggestions on how to do so.

EDIT: I was wrong about this being official, or at least have not found an official statement from Tor Project but did find this [answer.](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/69/696)

Answer (score 0):

First, using the Tor Browser, download the latest TBB for Linux, for your desired architecture (linux32 or linux64) and language, from [here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads). Unless you have saved anything that you want in the old TBB's root folder ("tor-browser_...") just delete the old TBB folder (and the old .tar.gz archive file, if you saved it).

If you did save stuff, temporarily move it to your ~/Documents folder. If there are Tor configuration options, such as bridges, that you want to migrate, make note of them. Also, if you have bookmarks, back them up to ~/Documents/bookmarks-yyyy-mm-dd.json and then restore to the new Tor Browser.

Now install TBB as explained [here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux). Work as **your username**, and **NOT** as root. Briefly:

```
user@host:~$ cd ~/
user@host:~$ tar -xvJf tor-browser-ARCH-3.6.2_LANG.tar.xz
```

"ARCH" is the architecture that you selected (linux32 or linux64) and "LANG" is the language. Now:

```
user@host:~$ cd tor-browser_LANG
user@host:~/tor-browser_LANG$ ./start-tor-browser
```

If you have created a shortcut for the Tor Browser, it should still work.

Also, I note that there's no particular magic about pasting a new version of a folder over an old one. In particular, there is no guarantee that doing so will overwrite all of the old data on disk. If that's a serious risk for you, you should be using Tails on a machine with no hard drive. Alternatively, you could use TBB on a dedicated machine with full-disk encryption (FDE). Even using Whonix or a Tails VM, FDE on the host is essential.

Comment: Tor Project recommends that you extract on top instead of replacing. To do so, extract in a folder then drag to containing folder of the original install. Click merge or replace if it asks.

Comment: @cammy_the_block, thanks. That turned out to be incredibly simple. I had backed up and exported my bookmarks as html as well and your method didn't even require that I replace them. I'm up and running. Again, thanks.

Comment: Well, you'll lose anything that you saved that way, but whatever. That's why people ask where their bookmarks went. And if you're counting on that to avoid leaving traces on the machine, good luck ;)

Comment: Perhaps add that noting down any used bridges might be good idea to make setup of the new TBB more easy.

Comment: @mirimir The bookmarks should be kept when using the method of extracting over the original install, as reported by ned.

Comment: @ned If my comment was useful feel free to accept/upvote my answer, which contains the same info as my comment.

Comment: @Cammy_the_block Please provide a cite for the "extract over" recommendation. I can't imagine ever doing such a thing and counting on the update not being too different. And whoever recommended it, it's a bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: @mirimir I was incorrect about this, which is further explained in my answer.