# How dangerous is it to run Tor without verifying the signature of the package?

Tags: verification, packages

I tried to follow the tutorial (https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) and also checked this forum looking for help ([Tor Browser-how to verify signature?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/tor-browser-how-to-verify-signature)) but none of the things I've tried have worked yet.

So, if I happen to be lazy and decide to go on and start using Tor Browser, how dangerous would it be to surf on the web using a non-verified Tor browser?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You better avoid this kind of running: when I helped people I saw a fake Tor Browser distributions: `tor.exe` binary was replaced with some malicious program that even tried to mimic original program's behaviour and even log output! So - do yourself a favour - check the signature. it *is* simple. Need help with signature checking?

Comment: Ok tanks. Yes, I need help with signature checking. As I posted, I've tried to do it several times without any success. I downloaded Tor Browser from the official website, so it is very unlikely to be a fake version. Yet, I prefer no to take any risks and verify it. I tried to verify it using gpg2. Could that be the problem? Do  I need to use another program?

Comment: @ÁlvaroMendoza use [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/). Install it, download your file and use a right click and tab "File Hashes" =)

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. It says "Without a licence for commercial use". There is an option of obtaining one, but you have to buy it from HashTab. Any steps I should follow? Do I have to do anything with the cmd? Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: @ÁlvaroMendoza then install 7Zip - it also enables a right-click "CRC SHA" functionality in Windows

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, I have been busy. I downloaded 7-zip. What should I do now? Which signature should I check: the .exe file, the .asc file or both? I have tried the right-click "CRC SHA" feature, but there are several options: CRC-32, CRC-64, SHA-1, SHA-256 and *. Which one should I check? Thank you very much.

Comment: EXE file - ASC file is a file with signature. If there's a "PGP xxx" stuff in it - you need a GnuPG based solution like [this](http://www.tech-faq.com/gnupg-shell.shtml)