# Difficulties right off the bat

Tags: exit-relays, help

What the heck is a relay & an Exit relay?
I assume that if I have to pay for bandwidth then operating as an exit relay is both costly & unwise?
How can I determine whether I am set up as an exit relay?

I have read all the stuff presented, but clearly it's not intended to help the uninitiated.
I gave up attempting to check the Tor download signature file, here again complexity seems to be the objective. 
In 2017 no-one should ever have to contemplate using a command line sequence of instructions to simply verify a file has the correct signature.
Frankly not understandable to anyone even with some modest IT skills.

Answer (score 2):

> What the heck is a relay & an Exit relay?

Read about it at: https://www.eff.org/torchallenge/what-is-tor.html
This is the simplest description of what is tor relay I could find.

> How can I determine whether I am set up as an exit relay?

First, find out were your config file (torrc) is located:

- For Windows its `%AppData%\Roaming\tor\torrc`
- For Linux its `/etc/tor/torrc`

If you find uncommented line like that: `ExitPolicy reject *:*` that means
that you are *not* going to be an exit relay.
Add this line if you don't want to be an exit relay.

---

Also It's very dangerous to host an exit relay.
Find out more about it here: https://blog.torproject.org/running-exit-node

> I gave up attempting to check the Tor download signature file, here again complexity seems to be the objective.

This was already asked on our forms: [Tor Browser-how to verify signature?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/tor-browser-how-to-verify-signature)
If you want you could use GUI like Kleopatra.